# Allow all characters and spaces restrictions regex javasctipt

Tags: javascript, regex, character, spaces

I found this regex which acomplishes the following:

```
^(\w+\s)*(\w+$)
```

- no space at beginning
- no space at end
- no double or more consecutive spaces in between

But I also need to allow any character and currently it only accepts alphanumeric values.

How do I write this?

Comment: Where do you need the "any character" ?

Comment: I use this site all the time .. It'll not only help you get your syntax right, it'll help you learn what the syntax means --  https://regex101.com/

Comment: any word for example: "Hello Wolrd Ca$h"
at any place really, beginning, middle or end

Comment: replace `\w` with `[^\s]`.

Comment: ASDFGerte's answer did the trick, thanks everyone
I would mark it solved, can it be done in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\w` (which matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) with `\S` (not a whitespace character, as mentioned in the comments. Should be equivalent to `[^\s]` but if there is a shorthand, better use it), making `^(\S+\s)*(\S+$)`.

Note that this matches everything that is not matched by `\s`, also any weird unicode symbols or the likes.

This is a token answer as there seem to be no answers after my comment and OP noted that marking as resolved cannot be done on comments.

Comment: `\S` is shorter than `[^\s]` and a more efficient will be `^\S+(?:\s\S+)*$` (if you place the quantified group closer to the end of the pattern (to reduce backtracking).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I often tend to forget things like `\S`. The different grouping sounds good as long as the capture groups were not needed for other reasons.